# Controlling DC motors with PWM in MCU

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, dc-motor, driver

[image]

1.Is this the correct way to control a DC motor using the PWM pins in the MCU?

2.How many PWM output pins do you need if you want to use a driver (ex: H-bridge) for each motor and control the duty cycles?

3.What are the schottky diodes in my schematic for?

Comment: It's good but you can use a driver IC like L298, this way you can spin your motors clockwise or counterclockwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can make this work.
2. Depends on your requirements. Roughly you'll need 1 pwm per motor with speed control and one gpio per direction. Fancy control would need one pwm per drive transistor.
3. Those are freewheeling diodes to give a conduction path for the motor inductance when the drive transistor turns off. It bleeds off energy stored in the inductance and armature inertia.